# jQuery use selector after .find()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a bit of code where I want to look at each row in a table and look for a particular  with a class specific class.

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("td").find(".group_name").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

So that all the td's with the class "group_name" are made red.

Comment: When are you calling this, by the way? Is there a particular reason you aren't just using a CSS definition to make the background color of all `<td>` elements with the class `group_name` red?

Comment: The code you showed is actually doing (note the space between td and .group_name):
$("tr td .group_name").css("background-color", "red");

Comment: Better still Why use Jquery at all . For styling use CSS as much as possible

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually this should be enough:

```
$("tr td.group_name").css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: Most of jQuery functions is already armed with .each() call inside of them :)

Comment: @chester1000: Yes, you just have to know which not ;-)

Comment: Thanks, most of my problem was coming from else where (flexigrid).

Comment: @chester1000 No, I'm sorry, most things work on collections. Try and error would be the easiest thing, if you don't like reading the documentation. You have to be aware, there is a difference in normal jQuery objects and jQuery collection objects. To put it simply: If it makes sense to you to apply a function to a collection, it will most probably work.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
$('tr').find('td.group_name').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?
This is much easier

```
$('tr td.group_name').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: @Neil As a general rule of thumb: If you're using a function that **sets** (be it an attribute, property, event handler, data, whatever) it will affect all elements in the jQuery object it's called on. If you're using a function that **gets** (such as `.val()`) it will only affect the *first* element in the jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over it...

When you do    `$("tr td.group_name")` it will select all the td elements inside tr that have class = "group_name"

So

```
$("tr td.group_name").css("background-color", "red");
```

Will be more than enough :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is really overkill here, since your end goal is to add a red background color to any `<td>` elements with the `group_name` class that are within a `<tr>` element (when are they not?). For that, you can just use a CSS declaration:

```
td.group_name {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is that what you want :

```
     $("tr").each(function() {
         $(this).find("td .group_name").css("background-color", "red");
     });
```